# Number of nonhuman primates dead in space exploration

Tags: history, animals, space-race

This statue, ["Sam", in Riga, Latvia, is dedicated to the animal cosmonauts who perished during space flight experiments](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/sam-space-monkey).

[image: "Sam", in Riga, Latvia]

As far as I know, there were a lot of dead dogs on space flights, but I don't remember any chimpanzees or other primates.

Are there any statistics on dead monkeys, apes or other nonhuman primates in space flight?

I will include both accidental deaths and deaths on purpose, when the animal is killed either during, or soon after the flight for a dissection.

Comment: one was *intentionally nearly killed* in the making of a space-related movie: [Did they torture and kill a monkey during the filming of Andromeda Strain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/110282/45856) See also the meta question [Do we count monkeys as crew?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1550/12102)

Comment: This looks pretty comprehensive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkeys_and_apes_in_space